# Colon : operator in a list

Tags: python, list, matlab

I am used to use Matlab and its powerful colon operator.
It seems that there is the equivalent in Python, but not completely when it contains dict.
Here is my example :

```
data = [
    {'key1' : 'value1', 'key2' : 'value2'},
    {'key1' : 'value3', 'key2' : 'value4'},
    {'key1' : 'value1', 'key2' : 'value5'}
]
```

`data[0:2]` works and returns `[{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}, {'key1': 'value3', 'key2': 'value4'}]` (however i would have instinctively used `0:1` to have this same result)

but

`data[0:2]['key2']` doesn't and returns `list indices must be integers, not str`

Should I conclude that `:` can be used only on list not containing dict, or I am typing it wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: You really should learn how to use range specifiers.  This is so fundamental to Python that you should have learned it within the first hour of using Python.  For list `x`, specifying `x[a:b]` returns a slice of `x` whose first index is `a` and last index is `b-1`, inclusive.  But it is still a list.  In your case, that list contains two dicts.  If you want to access a dict element, you must first select a single element from the list (or from the slice).  E.g. `data[0:2][1]['key2']`, or `data[1]['key2']`

Comment: Are you confusing the two different uses of `:`?  It's use when specifying a dictionary is not related in any way to it's use in a slice `[0:2]`.  Any *sequence* can be sliced, which includes lists, tuples and strings, regardless of the class of objects the elements refer to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I conclude that `:` can be used only on list not containing dict, or I am typing it wrong?

That's not a correct conclusion. `:` can be used with any list.

The problem is that `data[0:2]` is a list.
If you want to get a list of the `'key2'` values of the elements in `data[0:2]` then you need to write that as a list comprehension:

```
>>> [v['key2'] for v in data[0:2]]
... ['value2', 'value4']
```

If you prefer to use an operator instead of a list comprehension, you can use the following:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> map(itemgetter('key2'), data[0:2])
... ['value2', 'value4']
```